# Dropbox in a networked shared home folder environment

Tags: linux, command-line, dropbox, nfs

I've got access to a cluster of servers, and my home directory appears on all of them (as it's on a networked drive). I installed the CLI version of Dropbox on one of them, and when I make changes to files that are stored in Dropbox on that computer, Dropbox happily syncs them. But when I make changes to files stored in Dropbox on other computers in the cluster, Dropbox doesn't notice. If I restart dropbox:

```
python dropbox.py stop
python dropbox.py start
```

It realizes the files have changed and syncs them. Alternatively, if I run this on the server where the Dropbox daemon is running:

```
touch file
```

Then it'll realize it needs to sync.

I currently have the dropbox stop/start running nightly in cron and when I need to I use touch, but I'm wondering if there's something better I could do, even if it's still a hack. (Sorry, I don't have more details about how the networked drive / my home directory is setup.)

Comment: This is because dropbox uses filesystem notifications to identify changed files, and I don't think those work for remote filesystems.

Comment: OK, any manual solutions that don't require me logging into the  computer that Dropbox is running on? What would happen if I run Dropbox on multiple nodes at the same time?

Comment: Best solution is to run Dropbox on the server that's hosting the networked home folder, as it'll get the filesystem notifications regardless of which server in the cluster is writing to it.